# String operation in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

i have a string with 'MTRY,SRGTA N BM461 1197 ' and 'NO,JOHN BN1407003 1295815512 '

I need to get only the name and initial (if exists).
like MTRY,SRGTA N and NO,JOHN.

how to achieve this with a query.?
any ideas, please.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With older versions of mysql, you'd probably need to do something like match those having an initial and not separately for extraction, then combine the results, e.g:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(myString," ",2) 
FROM myTable
WHERE myString regexp '[A-Z]*,[A-Z]* [A-Z] ' 
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(myString," ",1) 
FROM myTable
WHERE myString not regexp '[A-Z]*,[A-Z]* [A-Z] ';
```

The regex's match all caps A-Z any number of times, followed by a comma, followed by any number more A-Z, followed by a space, a single capital letter, and a space. This matches the iniital case, so for those we substring to the second space, and for those this doesn't match (without an inital) we substring to the first space.

You can see this work here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88cb52/1/0

The newest mysql has `REGEXP_SUBSTR` but it doesn't support lookaheads so unfortunately still couldn't do it in a single query in that I could think of.